# How can i programatically get customer full addresses in string type?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-address

```
public function Address()
{
    $customerId = "8";
    $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
    $billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBilling(); 
    $shippingAddress = $customer->getDefaultShipping(); 
    return  $billingAddress;
}
```

In this code is only getting the id I want the address as a string.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting the Address Id, you need to load the Address using that Id. You can use the below code:

```
$address = $this->addressRepository->getById($billingAddressId);
$renderer = $this->addressConfig->getFormatByCode('html')->getRenderer();
return $renderer->renderArray($this->addressMapper->toFlatArray($address));
```

In Contructor you need to define the below classes:

```
\Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Config $addressConfig,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Address\Mapper $addressMapper
```

You can change the argument passed in `getFormatByCode` function to `text` as well.

Comment: which address i will get from the above code?only billing?

Comment: No you can pass any address id

Comment: ok thanks...is there anyway to get all the addresses using the customer ID?

Comment: You can get all address collection like this `$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();`

Comment: great ..If it worked for you, accept it as answer !!

Comment: you mean instead of using this $address = $this->addressRepository->getById(6); we need to use this code $addresses = $customer->getAddresses(); right?

Comment: yes if you want to load all address object, you can use this

Comment: i am getting an error like this ..""message": "Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\\Framework\\Api\\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter::toFlatArray() must implement interface Magento\\Framework\\Api\\ExtensibleDataInterface, array given, called in C:\\wamp64\\www\\firstmagento\\vendor\\magento\\module-customer\\Model\\Address\\Mapper.php on line 42 and defined in C:\\wamp64\\www\\firstmagento\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\Api\\ExtensibleDataObjectConverter.php on line 81""

Comment: can you please share your code snippet

Comment: This is my code: public function Address()
    {
        
        $customerId = "8";
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
        $renderer = $this->addressConfig->getFormatByCode('text')->getRenderer();
        return $renderer->renderArray($this->addressMapper->toFlatArray($addresses));
    

    }

Comment: `$addresses` is collection of address object. You need to use loop to get particular address object

Comment: can you please show me a example..?

Answer (score 0):

$customer->getDefaultBilling(); Will return address id only , to get the default billing address object use : $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();

And it workes the same with shipping address as well , hope this help :) .

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependency in the constructor method for class

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
```

And then to get address use below code

```
$billingAddress = $this->addressFactory->create()->load($billingAddressId);
print_r($billingAddress->getData());
```

Same for shipping Address.

Answer (score 0):

This will work Please check

```
$customerId = '9';

$customer = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);

$addresses = $customer->getAddresses();
```

Please note that `getAddresses` will return an array of

> Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface.

If you need the default billing address you can call:

```
$billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
```